# Android Java Hyper Link for IF Else

Tags: java, android, if-statement, hyperlink

I think this is the best place to post this. Could not find any good site to ask this. But here goes,

I am making a simple app, and I need the text to link to a webpage. The App randomly generates a set word each time the button is pressed. Here is the code.

This is a small amount of the code but it continues down for about 30 more if else.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // When the Button is Clicked
        String answer = "";

        //Random Answer Yes, No, or Maybe
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(30);

        if (randomNumber == 0) {
            answer = "TEXT HERE!";

        }
        else if (randomNumber == 1) {
            answer = "TEXT HERE!";

        }
        else if (randomNumber == 2) {
            answer = "TEXT HERE!";
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 3) {
            answer = "TEXT HERE!";
        }
```

how would I go about linking those words to a webpage? The links will be different though. So not all of the words will link to the same page.
I have had a look around online but I don't think it would work great using else if statements

Comment: Hi, some questions here: Why not use switch of even a for loop for the different values from 0 - to 30 (too much `ifs` - don't you think?)? Put your answers in string resources, avoid hardcoding inside the Activity. How do you want to link the words to a webpage - I don't understand this part?

Answer (score 2):

How about using an enumeration with all the information you want stored in it.
Like so:

```
public enum Answer {
     ANSWER1("TEXT HERE", "http://link.to.some/page")
     ANSWER2("TEXT HERE!", "http://link.to.some/other/page")

     private String answer;
     private String link;

     private Answer (String text, String link) {
         this.answer = text;
         this.link = link;
     }
     // plus getter and setter if you like
}
```

Comment: I don't really get how to do it. Should I erase all that I have done? Do I copy that code above all others? I reading up on enum now.

Comment: I think the best way to put, is there away to have these if (randomNumber == 0) {
answer = "TEXT_HERE!";
    
   }
else if (randomNumber == 1) {
answer = "TEXT_HERE!";
    
   }
else if (randomNumber == 2) {
answer = "TEXT_HERE!";
   } To get this text to link to a site? when it is on the Android? All the text will go to different pages.

Comment: This is just JAVA, the enumeration would help you with the relation of the answer as a text and its desired link. You wouldn't need the ifs and elses, you would just get the information by calling     Answer.values()[7] in combination with the getter for the property (answer or link). The example would give you the values for the eigthth value pair. With that you can actually refer the user to the web page. You probably would need an Intent for that if you do not have your own WebView.

Comment: If Bastian's answer does solve your problem, please accept it as the answer for your question.